# What's the difference between npm run dev and npm run start in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, npm-scripts

I am wondering what would the difference be between `npm run dev` and `npm run start`.
To my surprise, I could not find much information online about this topic.

Specifically, I'd like to know in the context of React and Next JS.

I noticed that with React, you can start your app by running `npm run start`, without the need of running a build first. On the other hand, Next JS doesn't seem to behave in the same way (but I could have done something wrong with the setup).
I tried running a new Next app using `npm run start`, as it's a default script in `package.json`, but it didn't work. It shows this error: `*Error: Could not find a production build*`

Instead, running `npm run dev` created a .next folder, and started the server on port 3000 with no issues.

Can anyone help me understand how this works?

Answer (score 52):

**TL;DR:** In Next.js, `next dev` is used to run the app in development mode. On the other hand, `next start` is used to run the app in production mode, but requires `next build` to be run first to generate an optimized production build.

---

### Development

When running the Next.js app in development, you'll want to use `next dev`:

> `next dev` starts the application in development mode with hot-code
> reloading, error reporting, and more.

### Production

When building the Next.js app for production, you'll want to use `next build`:

> `next build` creates an optimized production build of your
> application. The output displays information about each route.
>
> - Size – The number of assets downloaded when navigating to the page
>   client-side. The size for each route only includes its dependencies.
> - First Load JS – The number of assets downloaded when visiting the page
>   from the server. The amount of JS shared by all is shown as a separate
>   metric.

Followed by either `next start`, when you want to start the production server:

> `next start` starts the application in production mode. The
> application should be compiled with `next build` first.

Or `next export`, when exporting the app as [static HTML](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export):

> `next export` allows you to export your app to static HTML, which can be
> run standalone without the need of a Node.js server.

---

For more information refer to [Next.js CLI](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli) docs.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this depend on what is written in your package.json file. For example, in my case, within this file I got:

```
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --watch --watch-poll --progress --color",
    "prod": "webpack -p",
    "watch2": "webpack --watch --watch-poll --progress --color",
    "build": "webpack --config=webpack.prod.config.js --progress --watch-poll -p"
  },
```

so, if I run

```
npm run watch
```

I'll be compiling for development and it will be executed:

```
webpack --watch --watch-poll --progress --color
```

However, if I run

```
npm run build
```

it will be executed:

```
webpack --config=webpack.prod.config.js --progress --watch-poll -p
```

and it will compile for production.