# How can I resolve error that appear when I write "npm start" command in VSCode Terminal?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have this error when I write

```
npm start
```

command in VSCode Terminal:

> Error: Could not find a production build in the 'E:\React-Practis\nextjs-project2.next' directory. Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the production server."

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Please share what's written in scripts of package.json for npm start

Comment: You have to execute `npm run build` before executing `npm run start`, because `npm run start` will execute the build output inside `.next` folder. If you want to run in development environment, you may want to try `npm run dev` instead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [What's the difference between npm run dev and npm run start in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69400243/whats-the-difference-between-npm-run-dev-and-npm-run-start-in-next-js)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
npm run build
```

Then do this:

```
npm run start
```